# How to add select in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django

How can I add a a select field type in Django admin page of a table.
How does it store in Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add choices to a charField Type.

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/